# What is the difference between DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATE and HASH in Postgres XC?

Tags: postgresql, hash, cluster-computing, replication, distributed-system

According to the [SourceForge](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/sql-createtable.html) page for Postgres-XC, while creating a distributed table in Postgres-XC, it can take the attribute DISTRIBUTE BY with:

- **DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION:** Each row of the table will be replicated into all the Datanode of the Postgres-XC database cluster.
- **DISTRIBUTE BY HASH:** Each row of the table will be placed based on the hash value of the specified column. Following type is allowed as distribution column: INT8, INT2, OID, INT4, BOOL, INT2VECTOR, OIDVECTOR, CHAR, NAME, TEXT, BPCHAR, BYTEA, VARCHAR, FLOAT4, FLOAT8, NUMERIC, CASH, ABSTIME, RELTIME, DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMPTZ, INTERVAL, and TIMETZ.

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: I think the description is pretty clear: in the first case all rows of the table will be available in all nodes. In the second case one row is only stored on one node (based on the hash)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here, as the [documentation](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/sql-createtable.html) says and @a_horse_with_no_name has pointed out, ***Distribute by Replication*** will distribute all records to all nodes and ***Distribute by Hash*** will segregate the records by the column based on which it is hashed. For eg:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMPID INT, NAME TEXT) DISTRIBUTE BY HASH (EMPID) TO datanode1, datanode2;
```

Records are distributed among both the nodes.

Moreover, *Distributed by replication* is for ***read scaling*** -> Use coordinator to do DML, and fetch records from individual nodes.

*Distributed by Hash* is for ***write scaling*** -> Use nodes to do DML, and fetch records from Coordinator. Refer [this](http://manojadinesh.blogspot.in/2012/08/postgres-xc-setup.html?showComment=1436271398100#c4777815632085821626) for more information.